# Is there a way to make Google Maps JavaScript API V2 work?

Tags: google-maps-api-2

I have a drupal website which uses Gmap module with google API Key V2. Gmaps was working fine until few days back.

Currently if I try to search any location it gives me pop-up saying "Invalid API Key".

As per my research, this is happening since Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010.

I believe that an upgrade to v3 version should solve the problem but it is going to take me some time for the upgrade.

Is there some other alternative to somehow get my website working for a couple of months?

Can Google Web Toolkit be of any use?

Any help much appriciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is not related with the deprecation notice. V2 will be deprecated next month, so until that day you shouldn't have any issues, but obviously do not wait until then.
I too have a drupal site with V2 API maps, so I'll be spending some time migrating it.

The Invalid API key message is probably because you have, as the message says, a wrong API key in one of your files. Maybe the map that you use for searching comes from a different code with a different Key? Check that out...